# How to set APLN protocols before TLS handshake with OpenSSL in Rust?

Tags: rust, openssl, h2, http-1.1, alpn

I want to set the APLN protocols to `"h2"` and `"http/1.1"` before the TLS handshake. I am using [`.set_alpn_protos()`](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.31/openssl/ssl/struct.SslContextBuilder.html#method.set_alpn_protos). However, my attempt yields an error at runtime:

```
context.set_alpn_protos(b"\x06h2\x08http/1.1").expect("set ALPN error");
```

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'set ALPN error: ErrorStack([])', src/checker/tls/get_tls_info.rs:58:56
```

I can set them successfully in Python like this:

```py
ssl.set_alpn_protos([b'h2', b'http/1.1'])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

From the docs you linked (emphasis mine):

> It consists of a sequence of supported protocol names prefixed by their **byte length**.

replace `\x06` with `\x02` since `b"h2"` is `2` bytes not `6`

```rust
context.set_alpn_protos(b"\x02h2\x08http/1.1").expect("set ALPN error");
```

You could also use something like the following to calculate the wire format from a list similar to pythons:

```rust
let protos: &[&[u8]] = &[b"h21", b"http/1.1"];
let wire = protos.into_iter().flat_map(|proto| {
    let mut proto = proto.to_vec();
    let len: u8 = proto.len().try_into().expect("proto is too long");
    proto.insert(0, len);
    proto
}).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Comment: Thank for you help, you're right. I just missed that one
thanks again
Feel bad about my English....